# Piechart not displaying store data

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a pie chart in sencha-touch that is not retrieving data from my store, it is gender data coming from a mysql database, the data is being retrieved using an ajax request here is the request and the store

```
Ext.define('Qvidi.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
},

getGender: function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    class: 'Qvidi',
                    method: 'getDataM'
                },
                url: 'server/index.php',
                success: function( response ){
                    var r = Ext.decode( response.responseText );
                    Ext.getStore('GenderStore').setData( r.results );
                }
            });
}
```

});

and here is the store

```
Ext.define('Qvidi.store.GenderStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Qvidi.model.GenderModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'
],

config: {
    model: 'Qvidi.model.GenderModel',
    storeId: 'GenderStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        extraParams: {
            class: 'Qvidi',
            method: 'getDataM'
        },
        url: 'server/index.php'
    }
}
});
```

and lastly here is my model

```
Ext.define('Qvidi.model.GenderModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'types'
        },
        {
            name: 'counter'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

here is a log data from inspect in google chrome

---

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

sencha-touch.js:13032 The key "minimum-ui" is not recognized and ignored.
app.js:39 loaded

Console.js?_dc=1456999436953:35 [DEPRECATE][Anonymous] loadData is deprecated, please use either add or setData

---

The last log was after I changed setData to loadData

and here is the retrieved sql in my method decoded to json

```
    {
success: true,
total: 2,
results: [
{
types: "Male",
counter: 2182
},
{
types: "Females",
counter: 1134
}
]
}
```

here is my chart code

```
{
                            xtype: 'polar',
                            height: 377,
                            id: 'genderPieChart',
                            colors: [
                                '#115fa6',
                                '#94ae0a',
                                '#a61120',
                                '#ff8809',
                                '#ffd13e',
                                '#a61187',
                                '#24ad9a',
                                '#7c7474',
                                '#a66111'
                            ],
                            store: 'GenderStore',
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'pie',
                                    colors: [
                                        '#115fa6',
                                        '#94ae0a',
                                        '#a61120',
                                        '#ff8809',
                                        '#ffd13e',
                                        '#a61187',
                                        '#24ad9a',
                                        '#7c7474',
                                        '#a66111'
                                    ],
                                    labelField: 'types',
                                    xField: 'counter',
                                    yField: 'types'
                                }
                            ],
                            interactions: [
                                {
                                    type: 'rotate'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

here is my php code

```
class Qvidi extends Connect {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function getDataM( $vars ){
    $sql = "Select 'Male' as 'types', count(gender) AS 'counter' from quividi.vidireports where gender='1'
            union
            Select 'Females'  as 'types', count(gender) AS 'counter' from quividi.vidireports where gender='2'";
    $data = array();

    $total = 0;
    if( $result = $vars->db->query( $sql ) ) {
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            $data[] = array( "types"=>$row["types"], "counter" => intval ($row["counter"] ) );
            $total++;
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo json_encode( array( "success" => true, "total" => $total, "results" => $data ) );

}
```

Comment: Is the result correct?

Comment: the result coming from my php file is correct, the data is being retrieved properly, there are two data fields coming from the query it is the type, that being male or female and the other field being counter, that being the number of males and females.

Comment: type is a string and the counter is stored as an int value

Comment: can you post and example of a result console.log?

Answer (score 0):

ok so:

my php code

```
<?php
$callback=false;
if(isset($_REQUEST['callback']))
    $callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];



$dati=array(
    (object) array( 'types'=> 'Male', 'counter'=> 2182),
    (object) array( 'types'=> 'Female', 'counter'=> 1134)
);

$resultObj= new stdClass();
$resultObj->results=$dati;
$resultObj->success=true;
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($resultObj) . ');';
}else {
    echo json_encode($resultObj);
}

?>
```

my json response:

```
{"results":[{"types":"Male","counter":2182},{"types":"Female","counter":1134}],"success":true}
```

my model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.GenderModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.Field'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'types'
        },
        {
            name: 'counter'
        }
    ]
});
```

my store:
you will need these requires for the store:

```
requires: [
        'Ext.data.Store',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ]


myStore: {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'MyApp.model.GenderModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'myphpurl',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'results'
                }
            }
        }
```

my chart:

```
{
            xtype: 'polar',
            colors: [
                '#115fa6',
                '#94ae0a',
                '#a61120',
                '#ff8809',
                '#ffd13e',
                '#a61187',
                '#24ad9a',
                '#7c7474',
                '#a66111'
            ],
            bind: {
                store: '{myStore}'
            },
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'pie',
                    angleField: 'counter',
                    label: {
                        field: 'types',
                        display: 'rotate',
                        contrast: true,
                        font: '12px Arial'
                    },
                    xField: 'counter',
                    yField: 'types'
                }
            ],
            interactions: [
                {
                    type: 'rotate'
                }
            ]
        }
```

my final view:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Theres no change tothe pie chart, at all, theres no errors in the console, but like i said no changes, the piechart is not even visible anymore

Comment: can you try to load a sencha fiddle?

Comment: if you cant do the Ajax request set manually an example value on r.result value

Comment: add also the code of your chart on your question, maybe the chart is not setted good

Comment: why aren't you using an ajaxproxy on your store?

Comment: So maybe I didnt explain this, the Ajax request is in my controller I created, I should have said that before. I did not need a Ajax Proxy as the Ajax is done through the Ajax request in the controller

Comment: I just added the information now to where the ajax request is in my post

Comment: I know about that, but, an Ajax request should not be on the main program but should be done on a different task, usually to load a store directly with an ajaxrequest you should use an ajaxproxy on your store, so the store on load will to the ajaxrequest and load automatically

Comment: I just added the Ajax Proxy, How would I go about configuring it

Comment: your Ajax request is no more needed now

Comment: please check the green tick if the answer is correct

Comment: Hi sorry i disappeared for a minute, i am checking that now

Comment: But the issue still stands because, I cant just define an array, I will upload my php code to show you what I mean, I am getting Live data from a Camera gathering video analytics so i need it to update automatically

Comment: where is the problem? if you need to reload datas you only have to do a store.load() and the store will again send the request

Comment: the chart will change automatically, you only have to make a task to reload every x time the store

Comment: so on store load, the store will send the request to your php, and your php will do selects to return the json.